# Android: RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF does not work?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

another question for which I could not find answer:
I've got a RelativeLayout, that should have a button at its right edge and an ImageButton close to the left. And I do not know how to arrange this.

What I try is:

```
    RelativeLayout TopLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
    TopLayout.removeAllViews();
    TopLayout.setPadding(m_TableRowPadding_px, 8, m_TableRowPadding_px, 4);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(m_Resources
        .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ButtonWidth), m_DefaultButtonHeight_px);
    bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    Button itemAddButton = new Button(this);
    itemAddButton.setLayoutParams(bParams);
    itemAddButton.setText(m_Resources.getString(R.string.add_item_button));
    itemAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {...});

    TopLayout.addView(itemAddButton);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ibParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MIN_IMG_BUTTON_WIDTH,
        m_DefaultButtonHeight_px);
    ibParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, itemAddButton.getId());

    ImageButton speechButton = new ImageButton(this);

    speechButton.setLayoutParams(ibParams);
    speechButton.setContentDescription(m_Resources.getString(R.string.AddSpeechItemString));
    speechButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {... });
    speechButton.setImageDrawable(m_Resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.micro2));

    TopLayout.addView(speechButton);

  }
```

But the result is a button to the right (as desired) and a ImageButton to the left. :(

Could anyone help me? O.o

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set an id to the itemAddButton button before u use the line. Right now itemAddButton.getId() will just return -1.

```
ibParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, itemAddButton.getId());
```

You can set something like

```
itemAddButton.setId(5005000);
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Never thought, that the ID has to be set by the programmer :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding additional rule to your `speechButton`:

```
ibParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, itemAddButton.getId());
```

You can also use `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM` if that works better for you.